# Docker compose install error 'curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104' in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: docker

I am trying to install docker compose on the Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I tried installing using the official link here and followed the Docker Compose documentation given, but when i run the command

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

then after some time it gives me this error

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   617    0   617    0     0    613      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--   613
 24 8280k   24 2056k    0     0    789      0  2:59:06  0:44:27  2:14:39     0

**curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104**
```

Kindly help me on this i have tried many times but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the solution you wanted, but if you only need to download the file, and placed them onto `/usr/local/bin` directory, then `wget` can do that.

```
sudo wget https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -O /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

This will download and specify the path of the file to `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose`— which is I assume what'd you want to achieve.

#### Failing cURL command

There has been bug reports that describe the problem that you occured on [cURL's GitHub page](https://github.com/curl/curl), it is currently active and you may want to look at it → https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4409

Comment: It is a great point and helpful. Thanks for it.